# Setting-up ARcore with Vuforia

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, arcore

Hi im new to Unity3d and AR, and i need to setup Arcore to use with vuforia.

i already have the " core-1.7.0.aar " file in Assets/Plugins/Android folder
and i already set the AndroidManifest.XML in the same folder as the .aar file

```
  <application android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector" android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="fullSensor" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale|layoutDirection|density" android:hardwareAccelerated="false">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="unity.build-id" android:value="53bad2ba-a78a-4c14-9e44-e3d1cbb2f87c" />
    <meta-data android:name="unity.splash-mode" android:value="0" />
    <meta-data android:name="unity.splash-enable" android:value="True" />
    <!-- The following must be present to facilitate use of ARCore, if available -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.ar.core" android:value="optional" />
  </application>
```

and according to [Vuforia Guide](https://library.vuforia.com/content/vuforia-library/en/articles/Solution/arcore-with-vuforia.html) i need to edit the Build.gradle but i dont know How to do that from unity?

and also after i set this up, will the tracking be as good as ARcore or no?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export your project from Unity to Android Studio by selecting **Export Project** in the Build Settings window then press Build. Unity will ask where you want to save the output. This will give you access to all the Gradle files to follow the instructions provided by Vuforia.

[image: Build Settings]

[image: Exported files]